# why port 8080 stops working when https/http2 are both enabled in light-4j

Tags: http2, light-4j

In the old release of light-4j, we can start the server with both HTTP and https with port 8080 and 8443. However, after the upgrade to the latest version, we cannot enable both anymore. Here is the output.

HOST IP null
Http Server started on IP:0.0.0.0 Port:8443
Https Server started on IP:0.0.0.0 Port:8443

Answer (score 0):

By default only 8443 which is the HTTPS/HTTP2 port is enabled right out of the light-codegen. The reason is the most our users are using Consul with Kubernetes and Consul only gives host and port as the result of the lookup. That is why we can only enable either HTTP or HTTPS not both at the same time. As we provide default certs for both client and server, it doesn't make sense to use HTTP in my opinion unless you have tools that don't support HTTPS.

Comment: "Consul only gives host and port as the result of the lookup" - does it mean its a Consul issue? If so can it be extended somehow to give more information about multiple bindings/routes for the same lookup resource?

Comment: I don't think it is an issue for Consul as the product is basically a key/value store. For the service discovery, there is a lot more need to be added in my opinion. For example, Consul can calculate the latency of each service instance and return it to the client so that client can make smart decision to choose the fastest service instance. There is a lot to be done and we are working with Consul team to enhance it.